# array(...) in the representation of my array

Tags: python, arrays, output

When I'm printing my array I get something like this:

```
[array([[[[ 3.32450613,  1.40735694,  0.97335847],
         [ 1.45219359,  0.27907383, -0.36503905],
         [-0.0 ...
```

Does anybody know what the `array( ... )` is for? I can't recreate it by appending arrays so I'm kinda confused about its meaning.

Comment: Are you using NumPy?

Comment: I unpickled a Theano Tensor Type and appended what I got through the get_value() Method to a Python Array = [ ].

Comment: It is indeed a bumpy ndarray that is responsible for this. Thx for the fast answer and sry for this easy question. I just never realised that ndarrays get printed out like that.